# Send SMS using Twilio through Azure Mobile Service Script

Tags: node.js, azure, twilio, azure-mobile-services

I have a Upgraded Twilio Account and I want to send sms to any number using that Account. When I try to send sms from **http://bit.ly/twiliosms**, the SMS is successfully sent to the users. But what I want is to send the sms from Auzre Mobile Service.

When a new Data is inserted to the Azure Mobile Service, I want a particular User to get an SMS. Here is the Code that I have written so far in my Azure Mobile Service's Script:

```
function insert(item, user, request) {

var httpRequest = require('request');
var sid = "<< My SID >>";
var token = "<< My TOKEN >>"; 

var url = "https://" + sid + ":" + token +
         "@api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/" + sid + "/SMS/Messages.json";
var body = "From=" + "+1234567890" + "&To=" + "+88017*********" + "&Body=" + "Hello World, how are you.";

httpRequest.post({
    url: url,
    headers: { 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
    body: body
}, function (err, resp, body) {
    console.log(body);
});
request.execute();
}
```

I have properly inserted my SID and TOKEN as well the **From** and **To** Phone numbers. But the SMS is not being sent although Data is being Inserted to the Table.

So what can I do in here? Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Edit:

I have seen the Log. It says that my To Number is invalid. But it is my personal Phone number:

{"code": 21211, "message": "The 'To' number   8801******* is not a valid phone number.", "more_info": "https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/21211", "status": 400}

I have tried seeing the Doc. But no suitable solution is available. So, your help is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to solve the issue myself. What I needed to do is replace the "+" in Phone number with "%2B". Now the whole thing works properly. Below is the Code that works:

```
function insert(item, user, request) {

var httpRequest = require('request');
var sid = "<< My SID >>";
var token = "<< My TOKEN >>"; 

var url = "https://" + sid + ":" + token +
     "@api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/" + sid + "/SMS/Messages.json";
var body = "From=" + "+1234567890" + "&To=" + "%2B88017*********" + "&Body=" + "Hello World, how are you.";

httpRequest.post({
url: url,
headers: { 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
body: body
}, function (err, resp, body) {
console.log(body);
});
request.execute();
}
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi Tanvir, I'm a developer evangelist for Twilio. I notice you're using Node.js for your application. You might be interested in trying the Twilio helper for Node.js which makes calling API methods much easier: https://www.npmjs.com/package/twilio